# Running an MSBuild project from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am have built an MSBuild project that has 
the main .proj file with several Targets inside,
several .targets files
and several .rsp response files to run this project in several ways.  Such as
Build, Clean/Build/Deploy, Clean/Build/Test/Deploy.. You get the idea.

What I now want to do is take this MSBuild and run it in TFS scheduler after I pull the source code.  So the workflow should be
1.  Pull the source code in TFS
2.  Run MSBuild project in the scheduler so I might set up tasks to run hourly and nightly.

The MSBuild will take care of Deploying to IIS, unless someone has a more efficient way of deploying after an hourly build.

How can I accomplish this in TFS?

Thank you

Comment: Request is way too broad.  Perhaps try to find a getting started page/video from channel 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Team Explorer UI in Visual Studio to define a "scheduled" build definition.

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/11/creating-a-build-definition-in-tfs.aspx

If you want to take this to the next level, research "continuous integration" which is also a built in capability.